# PHPExcel: Trouble loading large file

Tags: python, php, phpexcel, openpyxl

I wrote a PHP script that relies heavily on PHPExcel that reads a large file, usually from Dropbox, to add a store's inventory to an the store's ERP website.

This script acts sporadically, sometimes it works and reads the whole thing and other times I get an error saying the maximum allowed memory on the same file. At first I thought this happened because the file was in Dropbox and somehow there was a faulty connection causing it to stop reading midway but I copied the file locally and the same thing happens.

I don't know why this happens and it's driving me insane. I was thinking about having the file be read by a python script instead since I've had better luck reading a large Excel file using openpyxl.

I have a question regarding this route.

I was planning to call the python script using php's **exec** function

```
exec("python tesscript.py <fileName>");
```

The thing about this PHP script is that the file will be sent to it via a form with a file selector on the previous script. Is it possible to pass the file using the exec function?

If you need any further information please let me know and I will gladly provide it.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're close to a solution using just PHP. Maybe it's worth pursuing that a little further to avoid unnecessary complexity. If the OOM error occurs 'randomly' when processing the same file (and I mean byte-for-byte the same!), then your application is probably running right on the edge of its memory limit. You might want to check how much free memory is available prior to processing the Excel file, and adjust the memory limit to include a safe margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've mentioned that the file is "large", it may be memory / execution time problem.

Please try adding the following 2 lines at the top of your PHP script (to allocate memory and allow longer execution time):

```
ini_set('memory_limit', -1); 
ini_set('max_execution_time', 7200);
```